# jquery ui drag and drop - call function on drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I want the `alert('dropped');` to execute when I drop an item into a div. The `drop` event handler doesn't seem to function.

```
$('.dropme').sortable({
    connectWith: '.dropme',
    cursor: 'pointer'
}).droppable({
    accept: '.button',
    activeClass: 'highlight',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $li = $('<div>').html('List ' + ui.draggable.html());
        $li.appendTo(this);
        alert('dropped');
    }
});
```

Here is a link to a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8snSf/2195/

Advice appreciated as always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because it's the `sortable()` plugin which has enabled the drag/drop behaviour. Therefore you need to use the `stop` handler of that plugin, not the `drop` of `draggable()`. Try this:

```
$('.dropme').sortable({
    connectWith: '.dropme',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var $li = $('<div>').html('List ' + ui.item.html());
        $li.appendTo(this);
        alert('dropped');
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8snSf/2196/)

Comment: Thank you very much,

Comment: No problem, glad to help